# Angular view doesn't get updated

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

My application performs a get request on ng-init as follows:

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller = "dashboardCtrl" ng-init = "getTables('<?php echo base_url();?>')">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="side-bar" class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <div ng-repeat = "table in tables" class="table-name" ng-click = "getColumns(table)">
                    <p>{{table}}</p>    
                </div>
            </div>
```

Then I want to perform another get request by using the ng-click directive that is auto generated by the ng-repeat you can see above. The problem is that I'm fetching the server side data correctly but my scope variable is not getting updated in my view. I have tried with $scope.$apply(fn) and $scope.$apply() but I get a $digest in progress error, here's my controller:

```
require(['app'], function(app){
 app.controller('dashboardCtrl',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.base_url = "";
    $scope.tablename = "";
    $scope.tables = "";
    $scope.columns = [];

    $scope.getTables = function(base_url){
            $scope.base_url = base_url;
            $http.get($scope.base_url + 'index.php/dashboard/getTables').success(function(data){
                $scope.tables = data; //this works fine
           });
    }

    $scope.getColumns = function(param){
        $scope.tablename = param;  
        $http({
            url: $scope.base_url + 'index.php/dashboard/getColumns', 
            method: "GET",
            params: {tableName: $scope.tablename}
        }).success(function(data){
            $scope.columns = data; //request works but columns doesnt get updated in view            
            console.log($scope.columns); //server data is showed in console
        });  
      }
   });
 });
```

Finally this is the partial that should render and iterate over the $scope.columns variable:

```
<section id="table-data">
  <p ng-repeat="column in columns">{{column}}</p> <!-- Doesnt display anything -->
</section>
```

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Do other Angular functions work or has everything stopped? Is `#table-data` hidden?

Comment: No, #table-data is not hidden. The functions work fine since every request gets the expected result.

Comment: Are you even getting data back? Also, is your ng-repeat(columns) in the same scope(ng-controller) as your tables?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting data back, I can show it in my console. My ng-repeat for columns is separated in another partial but this partial has the same controller.

Comment: Ahh! @user1659653 -- Same controller != same instance of that controller. They have two separate scopes. Do you have a common parent controller?

Comment: Can we see the other template with the columns ngRepeat? Scopes are inherited along DOM ancestry, so if both your column template and your table template are specifying the same controller, they will actually instantiate one each

Comment: Oh I see, that means they aren't going to share the same instance right? I don't have a parent controller.So I should consider them separately. I just tried it out and it works, now I'll need to organize the markup properly thanks for the help!